# Python3 - How to self-update application running as a service

Tags: python, service, tornado, systemd

I have a python application that runs as a service (it's a tornado web server).  I want to the application to be able to self-update as follows.

1. user uploads a package file that contains a new version of the application files
2. the web application launches a separate python (or script) application that does the following:

   - Turn off the main application (systemctl stop myapplication)
   - update the files from the uploaded package.
   - Restart the application with the updates installed (new version)

I've tried a nohup and double-fork approach to launch the "updater" program, but it appears as soon as I shutdown the application from the spawned child program, the updater dies and the process fails.  I'm not sure if this is because I'm not detaching the update process correctly (which I think I am) or if systemd process monitored of the service causes issues with this approach.

Any suggestions?  I'm considering using a separate application (tornado) running in parallel that I send a HTTP request to trigger it to control the parent application and do the install.

Thoughts?

-Jeff

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using either a separate application or even a separate script that runs in cron - unless you really need this to be "real-time".

Do consider what happens if the new application doesn't work and you need to start the old one...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, not the most elegant, but functional.

I created a one-shot systemd service that is dormant (non-enabled, not running).  All that this service does is execute my python update program.

Process:

1. Main service (application) starts the one-shot service
2. One shot service starts up,  stops the main service
3. One service installs updated application files
4. One shot service restarts the main service and exits
5. Main service is now live and updated.

Its bit more than that, but the implementation works.

-Jeff